# Wrong upload progress on IIS 8/Angular2+/C#

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows server 2012 RC running IIS 8. In this server I have two services, that run on port 80

- A HTML/JS site that will run in the client and make requests to another service.
- A WebAPI write in C# that will receive requests from client.
  One of the features of the site, is to upload files to server.

The problem is that when the WebAPI and the HTML site run in the same port, the upload progress I receive is wrong.

Ex.: If the upload is in 20%, I receive a report of 70%, and then in some moment before the upload is complete I receive a report of 100%.

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TSSA.jpg)

Code for receive the file in the back end:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadVideo()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new 
            HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        var streamProvider = new 
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(ServerPath);

        await 
        Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider)
    }
```

Code to upload the file in the frontend:

```
    uploadFile(formData) {
        this.uploadRequest = this.services.uploadVideo(formData, 
        this.video.Id).subscribe(res => {
          // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
          // Look for upload progress events.
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % 
            done:
            console.log(res.loaded + "/" + res.total);
            this.value = Math.round(100 * res.loaded / res.total);
            console.log(this.value);
            if (this.value == 100) {
              this.readyToPost = true;
            }
          } else if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
              this.uploadFinished = true;
          }
        });
    }
```

I made a test, and when the two systems run on different port, like 80 and 8080, the progress work just fine.

There's some configuration I can do to make the upload progress work when the two services are running on the same port?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't have two separate processes listening on the same port. How is the operating system supposed to know which one should serve any particular attempt to connect to the port? Don't forget this is at the TCP level, things like URLs etc are at a much higher level of the stack and don't come into the equation at all. The only way you could do it is to have both the services themselves running on different ports, and on port 80 run a HTTP reverse proxy which will forward requests to the other service based on the URL

Comment: P.S. If you've configured this all in IIS it will normally warn you if you try to bind two sites to the same port.